# Exercise 1.6 from Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise from Chapter 1 of Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis. This has been posted in different forms on StackExchange. However, I have a different question than what is provided elsewhere. The problem states:

Let $\delta = (\delta_1, \dots, \delta_d)$ be a d-tuple of positive numbers; for a subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ define
$$\delta E = \big\{(\delta_1x_1,\dots, \delta_dx_d ):(x_1,\dots, x_d) \in E\big\}$$
If $E$ is measurable, then show that $\delta E$ is measurable as well and
$$m(\delta E) = \delta_1\cdots \delta_dm(E)$$

I have proven that $\delta E$ is measurable. Thus, $m(\delta E) = m_*(\delta E)$, where $m_*$ is the exterior measure. For the second assertion, do the following deductions then hold?

$$m(\delta E) = m_*(\delta E) = \inf \Big\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(Q_j) : \delta E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty  Q_k\Big\} = \inf \Big\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty m(\delta Q_j) : E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Q_k\Big\}$$
$$= \inf \Big\{ \delta_1 \cdots \delta_d \sum_{j=1}^\infty m(Q_k) : E \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty Q_k \Big\} = \delta_1\cdots \delta_d m(E)$$

Here the infimum is taken over all coverings $\big\{Q_i\big\}$ of $\delta E$ by cubes in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: looks correct. let me just add that it might be easier to show this claim using Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Sounds good. I will look into the method using Fubini's Theorem as well.